# React useEffect looping many times when fetching data and setState using fetch API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, use-effect, use-state

Why is this triggering `fetchData` multiple times? The `console.log` seems to loop almost infinitely? How do I get this to run just once onload and trigger only once when `fetchData()` is called later? What am I doing wrong here or missing?

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  let fetchData = React.useCallback(async () => {
    const result = await fetch(`api/data/get`);
    const body = await result.json();
    setData(body);
    console.log(data)
  },[data])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  },[fetchData]);
```

Update (Additional Question): How to wait for `data` to populate before `return()` the below this now gives the error because it is null at first?: `data.map is not a function`

```
return (
    <select>
        {data.map((value, index) => {
            return <option key={index}>{value}</option>
        })}
    </select>
)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the `useCallback` hook you pass `data` as a dependency and also simultaneously change the value of data inside the callback by calling `setData`, which means every time the value of data changes `fetchData` will be reinitialized.

In the `useEffect` hook `fetchData` is a dependency which means every time `fetchData` changes `useEffect` will be triggered. That is why you get an infinite loop.

Because you want to fetch data once when the component is mounted, I think `useCallback` is unnecessary here. There is no need to memoize the function `fetchData` unnecessarily.

***Solution***

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
     const result = await fetch(`api/data/get`);
     const body = await result.json();
     setData(body);
    } catch(err) {
      // error handling code
    } 
  }

  // call the async fetchData function
  fetchData()

}, [])
```

If you want to log the value of `data` when it changes, you can use another `useEffect` to do that instead. For example,

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(data)
}, [data])
```

P.S. - Also don't let the promise get unhandled, please use a `try...catch` block to handle the error. I have updated the solution to include the try..catch block.

**Edit** - ***solution for the additional question***
There are two possible solutions,

Because you expect the value of `data` to be an array after the API call you can initialize the value of data as an empty array like,

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

But if for some reason you have to initialize the value of `data` as `null`. Here is how you can render the information returned from the API call.

```js
// using short-circuit evaluation
return (
    <select>
        {data && data.length && data.map((value) => {
            return <option key={`select-option-${value}`}>{value}</option>
        })}
    </select>
)


// using a ternary
return (
   <div>
    { data && data.length
       ? (<select>
            {
              data.map(value => <option key={`select-option-${value}`}>{value}</option>)
            }
           </select>
         )
       : <div>Data is still loading...</div>
    }
   </div>
)
```

Do not use `indexes` as `key`, use something unique for the key.

Comment: if then to render that data in the `return ( <div>{orgList}</div> )` (this is just for example).  It says: `Cannot read property of null` my guess is because the fetch call has not finished yet before the component renders?

Comment: This happens because `data` is still `null` on the first render. The fetch call happens after the component has mounted. Solution is to check if data exist before trying to access it's properties, you can achieve this by using a ternary operator or a short-circuit evaluation like this,  `{ data && <div>{data.anyPropertyofData}</div>}`

Comment: I updated the question above, could you show how to implement the ternary operator? Thank you I appreciate all of your help

Comment: Updated the answer as per your requirements, pls have a look.